# @Import not initializing beans

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I am trying to import a configuration class from my JAR. The config class has bean initialized as follows:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(Config.class)
public class Config {

 @Bean
  @ConditionalOnMissingBean(Base64.class)
 public Base64 base64(){
     return new DatatypeBaseConverter64();
 } 
}
```

i tried to import this class from my jar in the configuration class of my project in this manner:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Import({Config.class})
public class Configure {
  //@Bean
   //public JwtService permissionsService()throws URISyntaxException,IOException{
   //   return new JwtService(new SecretKeyProvider());
   //}
}
```

when i run my project , i get the following error.

```
Field base64Converter in com.p2s.security123.service.JwtService required a bean of type 'com.p2s.security123.DatatypeBaseConverter64' that could not be found.
Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.p2s.security123.DatatypeBaseConverter64' in your configuration.
```

My Base64 interface:

```
public interface Base64 {

    String encode(byte[] bytes);

    byte[] decode(String base64);
}
```

JwtService class:

```
@Component
@Service
public class JwtService {

   @Autowired
   DatatypeBaseConverter64 base64Converter;
......
}
```

DatatypeBaseConverterBase64 class:

```
public class DatatypeConverterBase64 implements Base64 {

    @Override
    public String encode(byte[] bytes) {
        return printBase64Binary(bytes);
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] decode(String base64) {
        return parseBase64Binary(base64);
    }
}
```

JwtService, Base64, DatatypeConverterBase64 and config are in my jar and Configure class is in my project.
Thanks.

Comment: what is this `@ConditionalOnBean(Config.class)
public class Config {`you are putting a conditiona on a bean to scan the same bean ?

Comment: @ConditionalOnBean checks if a particular bean is defined or not and then creates it. if it is already present, it doesnt create again. It is for avoiding repetition.

Comment: what you are talking is `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` and not `@ConditionalOnBean`

Comment: Also try declaring your autowired field as a `Base64` instead of a `DatatypeBaseConverter64` .

Comment: Can you make it more clear what is in jar and what is not? It seems like DatatypeBaseConverter64 cannot be found and as Berger wrote, your base64 returns interface...

Comment: Oops, sorry..I have added all of them. Thanks.

Comment: pvpkiran yes you're right. I have tried with @conditionOnMisssingBean. But its giving the same error.

Comment: Yes I created this class. i used javax.xml.* library for the parse and print functions.

Comment: @Berger Thanks! that worked. Any explanation for that?

Comment: @VaibhavSavala : Yes, you declared your `@Bean` as returning a `Base64` object, but the autowired field is a `DatatypeBaseConverter64` (which is a subclass, not a parent class) , so the type doesn't match at all. Another way would be to declare your `@Bean` as returning a `DatatypeBaseConverter64 `, but usually it is better to work only with interfaces declaration without knowing implementations,  like the way suggested in my other comment .